# Цикл с построчной подстановкой данных (telegram-cli|.sh)

Tags: linux, циклы, telegram, sh

Имеется файл с никами (test.list), каждое слово с новой строки.

```
 test
 stack
 over
 flow
```

Надо цикл, который с определенной задержкой будет выполнять ряд команд в telegram-cli.

```
 sleep 1m
 echo "set_username НИК"
 echo "msg user text"
 done | /home/ubuntu/tg/bin/telegram-cli -w test.list
```

Что-то вроде такого, только как начать сам цикл, что бы каждый раз брался ник с новой строчки?

Желательно на SH, но можно любой яп.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

видимо, примерно так (если я правильно понял, что ваша программа `~/tg/bin/telegram-cli` читает написанные вами команды из своего *stdin*, выполняет их, и тут же завершает работу):

```
cat test.list | while read n; do
  sleep 60
  echo -e "set_username $n\nmsg $n text" | ~/tg/bin/telegram-cli
done
```

---

#### дополнение

если между переданными строками надо вставить паузу в, например, две секунды, то можно воспользоваться блоком `{ команды; } | программа`:

```
{ echo "set_username $n"; sleep 2; echo "msg $n text"; } | ~/tg/bin/telegram-cli
```

---

если же потребуется более «тесное» взаимодействие с запускаемой программой (например, ожидать вывода программой в *stdout* какой-то определённой информации и только после этого что-то передавать ей на *stdin*), можно воспользоваться программой [expect](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect).

Comment: Спасибо, но возникла еще одна проблема. Что бы отправить сообщение юзеру надо найти его через поиск. 
`echo "set_username $n\ncontact_search MyUSERNAME\nmsg NAME TEXT | ~/tg/bin/telegram-cli`
Но тг-кли не успевает выполнить команду `contact_search MyUSERNAME` и выполнить `msg MyNAME text` не может.
Можно как-то добавить задержку в 1-2 секунды между выполнением этих 2 команд? Или открыть терминал тг-кли и просто с задержкой в 1 минуту посылать 2 команды, что бы сессия тг не прекращалась?

Comment: @BoberMod, я дополнил ответ на основании вашего комментария. информацией, изложенной в вашем комментарии, лучше бы дополнить сам вопрос (нажав «править» ниже текста вопроса).